# scraping an XML webpage with IMPORTXML

Tags: xml, google-sheets

I am trying to scrape this webpage: https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/654008
to obtain in tabular format some of the values in XML:
legalName, shortName, country, id, city, vatNumber, ecContribution, etc.

Here is an [example with headers](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B4URi1k_irOpDlSYIPPWNv7U_KBEae97nM6y-GHY25g/edit#gid=1175078287) of the table I wish to obtain.

I have tried using IMPORTXML in Google Sheets but with no great success so far.
My problem is that I cannot identify the correct xpath query, even when using chrome extensions like SelectorGadget and XPath Helper who generally helps you find them.

One note: it seems that the "coordinator" table use different html tags.
Do you have any suggestions to correctly scrape this page? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

When we try to fetch this page directly it returns **JavaScript is disabled on your browser.** But when we analyze requests of the page we find a request than returns all data you need as a JSON. It's

> https://cordis.europa.eu/api/details?contenttype=project&rcn=654008&lang=en&paramType=id

We fetch this page via [**URLFetchApp**](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app), and push data we wish to an array, then write them to our sheet.

```js
function fetch() {
  var url = 'https://cordis.europa.eu/api/details?contenttype=project&rcn=654008&lang=en&paramType=id';
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var json = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()).payload.organizations.participants;
  var array = [];

  json.forEach(el => {
    array.push([el.name, , el.country.name, el.organizationId, el.address.city, , el.contribution]);
  })
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('main');
  var myRange = ss.getRange(2, 1, array.length, 7);
  myRange.setValues(array);

}
```

Comment: wahoo, not easy to find, how did you catch that url ?

Comment: @MikeSteelson By `DevTools > Network > Search` :)

Comment: The problem of my solution is that `shortName` and `vatNumber` don't exist in this page. However @player0 's solution gets these info as well.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this will help:

```
=INDEX(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(FLATTEN(IMPORTDATA(
 "https://cordis.europa.eu/project/id/654008/en?format=xml")), 
 "where Col1 contains 'country'"), ">(.*)<"))
```

[image]

Comment: Ingenious. Can we use that link in `IMPORTXML()` directly?